# Usage history displaying data despite no use for over a month

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, shutdown

Using a MacBook Pro (2021) running macOS 12.6

Went on holiday and came back to a dead MacBook, despite it being shutdown; used the commands `last shutdown` and `last reboot` in the terminal to verify this.

The attached screenshot was taken on the 24th Dec and shows usage from just a few days prior. Despite being last shutdown on the November 11th. So I'm wondering what caused it to turn on.

[image: You can see the energy usage & screen on usage]